# 'Challenge thinks' meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have found the sentence bellow. But I don`t understand very well what it means

> Challenge things I believe to be wrong and be open to challenge from
>   others.

The top sentence is from:

> **Respect**
>   
>  ...
>   
>   
> **Integrity**
>
> We act fairly, ethically and openly in all we do.
>   
>  - Show the courage to do and say right thing
>   
>  - Act in private as I do in public, and honour my commitments
>   
>  - **Challenge things I believe to be wrong and be open to challenge from others** 
>   
>  - Be accountable for failure as well as success, and allocate blame.
>   
>   
>  **Service**
>   
>  ...
>   
>   
> **Exelence**
>   
>  ...
>   
>  
>   **Stewardhip**
>   
>  ...

Source https://www.home.barclays/about-barclays/barclays-values.html#integrity

Comment: Where did this come from? I'm fairly sure my answer is right, but I can't be sure without some context.

Comment: It come from a company policy description about integrity. Problem is that I not very well understand what is want to say with this sentence. Maybe," to be ready to get tasks from others ".

Comment: Please include context and/or a source so that we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Added context to post

Answer (score 1):

The subject has been omitted in this sentence, or this quote is only part of a sentence. This is commonly done in affirmations or pledges. For example:

> I promise to:
>
> - Be respectful to all those I meet
> - Challenge things I believe to be wrong and be open to challenge from others